# How I set default value to zope.schema.datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, zope, dexterity

I codding a product using Python Dexterity Type, and I have one field shema.Datetime (see below), And I want set a default date time when form was create in Plone.

I tried using Zope DateTime and Python DateTime, and don't work.
In [docs zope schema](http://docs.zope.org/zope.schema/fields.html#datetime) don't have examples for this.

```
# I'm tried use this options with DateTime
from DateTime import DateTime
# DateTimeNow = DateTime()
# DateTimeNow = DateTime().asdatetime()

# And tried use datetime
import datetime
DateTimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()

class IDigitalFile(model.Schema):
    ...

    uploded_at = schema.Datetime(
        title=_(u"Data de Upload"),
        required=True,
        defaultFactory=DateTimeNow,
    )
```

So, How I set default value in this case?

Comment: Try to use ``DateTimeNow = datetime.datetime.now``, without parens.

Comment: What @turkus said, or in other words pass it *a (factory) callable producing a value* instead of *the value*. From [plone docs](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/defaults.html): "The defaultFactory is a function that will be called when the add form is loaded to determine the default value."

Comment: @turkus I tried n my output is `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    unhashable type: 'list'
> /home/jafar/training/buildout/eggs/zope.interface-3.6.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/interface.py(415)get()`

Comment: Does this error points to line with DateTimeNow? I think this error is about something else.

Comment: @turkus if I choice `DateTime()` or `DateTime().asdatetime()` or `datetime.datetime.now()`or `datetime.datetime.now`or `DateTime().asdatetime` the output error is diferent... I think its belong. If you see the error show `type: list`, so, the question is, what type `schemaDatetime .. defaultFactory` accept? In Zope Doc say: `represented as a a Python datetime.DateTime.`so... I set and don't work. I can post all code to you see... if u want. I found this http://docs.plone.org/4/en/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/defaults.html, And don't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using Python Datetime, and not Zope DateTime, see code:

```
from datetime import datetime
...
def nowDateTime():
    return datetime.today()

...
directives.mode(uploded_at="hidden")
uploded_at = schema.Datetime(
    title=_(u"Data de Upload"),
    required=True,
    defaultFactory=nowDateTime,
)
```